# checkbox control with no action buttons on job messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The tab messages shows you specific messages (incoming / outgoing) within the jobs tab of stackoverflow.  But the checkboxes do not have any action buttons associated with them, so I don't see any purpose in having them:

[image]

So I can check the checkbox but it doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: The action buttons should be right under your "no action buttons" text. They are "Mark as unread" and "Mark as read". You don't see them?

Comment: But jason those only appear in your inbox, try the other tabs like sent / applications / messages.

Comment: Ahhh. I see now.

Comment: @Jason so from this day on, Careers meta is MSO, not MSE? That's a major change, and you have tons of questions to migrate in this case.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yes. Agreed it's big. We're gonna move all the questions here in a little bit.

Comment: @Jason oh well. I used to try and help a lot with Careers on MSE. So, less work for me. :)

Comment: Shadow Wizard - You can still help, that is the beauty of all of this.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there's no point in showing checkboxes here if there aren't any action buttons for you to do anything with the selected messages.

I've now removed the checkboxes from the Sent tab (and its sub-tabs).