# Migration of questions loses critical information

Tags: discussion, migration, views

This question was viewed close to 800 times [Apply pop-up does not make it clear which version of resume will be attached](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312567/apply-pop-up-does-not-make-it-clear-which-version-of-resume-will-be-attached).  Suddenly this question was migrated from Meta Stack Exchange to Meta Stack Overflow.

Couple of things here:

1. When migrated a question the information about the migration does not tell me who migrated and when it was migrated (confusing)
2. The count of views is completely lost, now we have 3 views on this question.  I believe view count plays an important role in search as well as visibility.  Is it okay that this information is now lost?

Comment: Yannis - I missed that thanks, however the view counts are lost.

Comment: That's a rather minor loss, which *you* caused by posted to the wrong meta initially.

Comment: Ben Voigt - I did not post in the wrong meta...careers was ALWAYS in meta stackexchange.  See shadow wizards comments http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312555/checkbox-control-with-no-action-buttons-on-job-messages?noredirect=1#comment283867_312555

Comment: Careers may be Stack Exchange-specific, but the Jobs tab was always tied to Stack Overflow, so moving it to this meta was the right call.

Comment: @JonH: Careers has always been associated with SO specifically, not SE in general.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ben then maybe you should transfer all 50k career related questions to meta so rather than meta se?

Comment: @Makoto - Its the right call NOW but it was never built inside of SO until yesterday...

Comment: @JonH: A bunch seem to be here already (and not just migrations): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/careers

Comment: Arguing over where it was initially posted is sort of pointless.  We always allowed careers stuff to be posted on MSO or MSE.  The post was migrated here because Jobs is now tied directly to SO.

Comment: @bluefeet - And that's fine my point is I was told you posted in the wrong area, and my answer was NO I didn't as when I posted that post most career related issues where posted on MSE as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information about who and when migration happened is thoroughly documented in the migration banner and linked revision history ([Ben Voigt's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312569/migration-of-questions-loses-critical-information/312570#312570) provides a good demonstration of this).

View count and some other stats are not migrated; there are arguments to be made for migrating it, but there's also a huge amount of value in knowing how many people saw the question in its original location vs. its final destination as well. Migration is always a tradeoff in some fashion, and should be used sparingly for this reason.

My three guidelines for migration remain:

1. If the question is on-topic for the site where it was asked, and it is answered, DO NOT MIGRATE unless the authors of the question and/or answers badly want it moved.
2. If the question is off-topic *or unanswered* and there's good reason to believe someone wants to answer it on the destination site, then migrate as long as it's on-topic at the destination.
3. If the question is off-topic but seems reasonably well-written and you understand it well enough to believe it belongs on the target site, migrate.

There's a third consideration when it comes to meta sites: bugs and feature-requests can legitimately be reported on *multiple* sites, but are often fixed once across all sites - thus, it can be advantageous to move them to one location prior to marking them fixed. Even on meta sites, migration should generally be used sparingly though; shuffling around reports that aren't currently being addressed is confusing to those asking them and busywork for those moving them.

Comment: Thanks you this answers my question!

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce, the information on who and when is clearly visible from the link in the migration notice:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/270890/revisions

[image]

Comment: What about the view count?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is critical in a general case that either the reason or the view count is preserved.

There stays a migration stub behind for  while to hold that information.

I think it is fair to reset the view count when a post is migrated as it starts a new life on the correct site. As such the view count indicates how many views it has at its new home.

The reason for migration might not always be obvious but I wouldn't care much unless the post would be rejected on the target site because the migration was useless in the first place.

The post was migrated from MSE to MSO because a high-rep user started a close voted on it. The SE employee that added the tag also acknowledged the Close Vote by migrating the post. I don't understand that because the feedback link on Careers points to MSE, not to MSO.

Either the team is planning on moving the support to MSO (which I can understand given the upcoming integration) or forgot to update their support link on Careers. I personally wouldn't migrate bug-reports between meta sites but that is not my call.

Comment: This post clearly says that Meta SO is the place: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow?cb=1

Comment: @BenVoigt That post is about jobs, that is not yet rolled out officially and the bug report was about the current Careers site. The support link  still points (I checked that before posting) to MSE. So the current/live/production site directs its users not only clearly but also actually to MSE.